# Pass a custom response from API call into fetch()

Tags: javascript

Here is the current situation:
I have a form, which grabs data and using `fetch()` it passes the data to a separate, processing page, where an API call in made server-side. This is my fetch:

```
             fetch("xxxx", {
                      method: "POST",
                      headers: {
                          "Content-Type": "application/json"
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify({
                          fileEnc: fileEnc,
                          fileName: fileName,
                          fileType: fileType
                      })
                  })
                  .then(function(res) {
                      console.log("Success!", res);
                  })
                  .catch(function(err) {
                      console.log("Error!", res);
                  });
          };
```

As a result, `console.log("Success!", res);` shows the following:

> Response {type: "basic", url: "xxxxxx", redirected: false, status:
>   200, ok: true, …}

This response shows that the data was successfully POSTed into the processing page.

**What I would actually like to do, would be to show the response that comes from the API call which happens in my server-side script inside the processing page.**

I tried this is my processing page, but it did now show up in the response on the first page:

```
var res = apiCall.statusCode
```

I am logging this into a table and I can see the `res` is populated and saved correctly for all the API calls, but it's not returned in the `fetch()` in my client-side script.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should probably do something like `.then(function(res) { return res.json() }).then(function(json) {console.log(json) })`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Fetch returns the response in the below format which is expected.

[Fetch MDN Response structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

In order to get data simple resolved promise with `response.json()`

So, code will look like

```
.then(function(res) 
  { return res.json() })
.then(function(json) {
  console.log('data', json) 
})
```

and get the response from it

To use the same in server side code, you need to use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you're saying I basically need to "fetch it back" to my first page?

Comment: Where are you storing your apiCall response? would you like to add some server side call for the API? I thought you need assistance at server side.